# Abstract Class - override or rewrite?

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, abstract-class

I have a custom module for checkout. I want to add some custom code for function `_getStepCodes()` in `app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Onepage/Abstract.php`

I found that abstract functions cannot be override or rewrite.

How can I add custom to the function `_getStepCodes()` in my custom module. Is it possibe to add this function to `app/code/local/Vendor/Modulename/Block/Onepage/Abstract.php` ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It must be understood that `Abstract` class can't be **rewrited** but **overrided**.

**The reason** is : because the abstract classes are not instantiated !

> Rewrite : When you add config nodes in `config.xml`.
>
> Override : When you copy the class from `core` to `local`.

If you want to customise some method in this abstract class, you have to copy the same path to your local, in your case: from `app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Block/Onepage/Abstract.php` to `app/code/local/Mage/Checkout/Block/Onepage/Abstract.php`.

So here Magento takes first the folder from **local**, he takes what you have updated then he go the **core** one.

Comment: I want to add all custom code to my custom module. Is it possible to add the function to app/code/local/Vendor/Checkouykout/Block/Onepage/Abstract.php rather than copying to  app/code/local/Mage/Checkout/Block/Onepage/Abstract.php ?  I hope my question is clear.

Comment: I didn't understand, please read again my answer carefully.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I understood your answer. As I am writing this as a custom module, on disabling this module, the default checkout should work. The file location app/code/local/Mage/Checkout/Block/Onepage/Abstract.php will not be a part of my custom module. ie what I am asking is it possible to include my custom code function to custom module only.